# SpreadsheetApp.openById error using appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm importing data from one sheet to another sheet using Google Appscript. However when I run the code there's an error occuring.

```
function importdata() {
    var mainfile = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data1');
    var secondfile = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1232131231231abcc').getSheetByName('RAW');
    var datas = secondfile.getRange('C:C').getValues();
    var paste = mainfile.getRange('A:A').setValues(datas);
}
```

Message details

> Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 27441 but the range has 27509. (line 6, file "Code")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)** expects your range to have the same length as the length of data you are trying to set (must match dimensions of your range).

try something like

```
var datas = mainfile.getRange('A:A').getValues()

var range = secondfile.getRange(1,1,datas.length);
range.setValues(datas);
```

**Update**: I actually think you might have "hidden" rows in your dataset, this might cause range to be confused with length.

Comment: Hi, check the udpate, please, if you have hidden rows - they were causing the issue, thus they are not copied to your second file if you use this method. Unhide them first.